# I am looking for a quality search plugin

Tags: catalogsearch

I am looking for a plug in to expand search functionality.  May I ask for recommendations and if there are pros or cons to others?

Comment: which type of functionality do you want to extends?

Comment: Giving weight to keywords and less common connectors like "A, and, & the."

Comment: Are you looking to simply extend Magento's default search engine or are you willing to install a third-party search solution on your server? This solution is preferred for most advanced search functionality. Research SOLR, Lucene or Sphinx Search. There are lots of Magento plugins available for these.

Comment: Im looking at 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company uses Blast Lucene, their support is decent and once you get the hang of how it works from an admin standpoint, their search works pretty nicely.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blast-lucene-search.html

Comment: And the newest version allows you to add weighting to custom attributes. With adding a `supplemental search` text area of 1.5 weighting to put in a comma delimited list of alternate names, industry terms, manufacturer part numbers and a `search priority` text field of 3.0 weighting, you can SEO your own Magento search to be highly relevant beyond the already excellent search returns.

Answer (score -2):

Internal Magento is <50% accurate, Sphinx/Lucene are 60-80% accurate, Solr is 98% accurate (we install this one normally), it is really that simple. After that which extension you choose is dependent on business requirements vs cost.

Comment: Where you find these "percentages". How you calculate these values?

Comment: I'm not developer of sphinx search, but use it for many projects. I just want understand, how you calculate this percentages. I think Internal Magento accurate less then 50%. Sphinx/Lucense/Solr with same confiugration return +- same accurate.

Comment: He makes up his answers and adds random percentages to support them. The sad thing is, he doesn't even know that SOLR is based on Apache Lucene, making his answer even more ridiculous. Please ignore anything he comes out with!